# how to refresh screen on stack navigation

Tags: react-native, expo

I started using useContext in some screens.

1)HomeScreen - createContext and pass it to those two screens by Provider

2)FirstScreen - display value of context that updated by SecondScreen

3)SecondScreen - update Context value and go back FirstScreen

I expected When I back from SecondScreen to FirstScreen, FirstScreen is refreshed and display newest value of context, but acutually there is no refresh event occurs so the value displayed was old one.

I do not need to pass context from SecondScreen to FirstScreen, so I do not want to do setParam on navigation.

how can I solve this?

update

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

const FirstScreen = ({navigation} => {
  const [stateText, setStateText] = useState('')
  const contextText = useContext(ContextText) // this is updated by NextScreen
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
       console.log(contextText) // this shows newest context
       setStateText('something') // it does not help to re-render screen
    })
    return unsbscribe
  })

  return <Text>{stateText}</Text> // ???????
//  return <Text>{contextText}</Text> // this shows old context
})


const NextScreen = () => {
  //...
  handleContextUpdate('anything')
  navigation.navigate('First')
  //...
}
```

I want to use useContext!!! I wonder I do not have to update context inside the unsubscribe function. is it true?

Answer (score 1):

You can add focus listener and refresh the data like

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
function AppScreen({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Call any action and update data
    });

    // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return <View />;
}
```

source : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/

Answer (score 0):

If you use functional component then use

```
 function screen1({ navigation }) {
      React.useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
          // The screen is focused
          // Call any action
        });
    
        // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
        return unsubscribe;
      }, [navigation]);
    
      return <View />;
    }
```

If you use class component then

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this._unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
     //call your function that update component 
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: thanks. I put setState in the unsbscribe but nothing changed. I though addListener('focus'. () => setSomething('something')}) may work re-render the screen but  it does not.